# Concatenate and preserve format in excel

Tags: excel

I have Excel table when one cell has 'text' formating and literally is A1 ABC: and second cell is custom formatting and literally is B1 2013-11-4
I need in the third cell C1 to concatenate both and get ABC:2013-11-4
I tried this: =concatenate(A1,A2) but it resulted in ABC:41582
My question: how could I concatenate A1 and B1 in order to keep custom formating of B1 cell?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the date format within the concatenation. The concatenation is retrieving the value behind the cell.

Instead, you can easily specify the date format using `TEXT(cell, format)`:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"YYYY-M-D"),A2)
```

The `YYYY`, `M`, and `D` represent four digit year (2013), month (11), and day (4) respectively.

Comment: @susik: Great, please mark this as the accepted answer to let future viewers know. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

The Answer provided by grovesNL fixed my problem.
Ticket could be closed.

Comment: I don't know 'why' BUT I can't mark grovesNL answer as 'accepted' neither comment on his post. That' weird